# Oauth2 gives invalid_grant" "Malformed auth code without sign in

Tags: go, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I am using following example code provided at the docs :

```
package main

import (
   "fmt"
   "log"

   "golang.org/x/oauth2"
   "golang.org/x/oauth2/google"
)

func main() {
   // Your credentials should be obtained from the Google
   // Developer Console (https://console.developers.google.com).
   conf := &oauth2.Config{
       ClientID:     "YOUR_CLIENT_ID",
       ClientSecret: "YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET",
       RedirectURL:  "YOUR_REDIRECT_URL",
       Scopes: []string{
           "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery",
           "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/blogger",
       },
       Endpoint: google.Endpoint,
   }
   // Redirect user to Google's consent page to ask for permission
   // for the scopes specified above.
   url := conf.AuthCodeURL("state")
   fmt.Printf("Visit the URL for the auth dialog: %v", url)

   // Handle the exchange code to initiate a transport.
   tok, err := conf.Exchange(oauth2.NoContext, "authorization-code")
   if err != nil {
       log.Fatal(err)
   }
   client := conf.Client(oauth2.NoContext, tok)
   client.Get("...")
}
```

After I run, I saw the link. Before I  click on the link, I got invalid grant error. Could you help me ?

Comment: You're not supposed to Exchange in main. That has to happen in the HTTP handler for the RedirectURI (the code will be in the query string). The authorization code is generated by Google. You can't just make one up and expect Google to know what to do with it.